# my react project wont start back up using local host?

Tags: reactjs, json, localhost, node-modules, npm-start

I am trying to update my react portfolio but to do that i have to be able to work on it. I have it up on heroku working and online. I pulled it up on my code editor and I do npm start and it compiles successfully but it wont go onto my localhost. Im wondering if anybody has an idea of why it wont come up. thanks a bunch

Comment: Do your project run successfully without any error?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can put your project in github and uplaod it to heroku through your repository and then you can change you code , run it in localhost and changes will automatically get applied to your protfolio online